# how to add discount and apply on order in admin

Tags: magento2.3

I need an input field in order create in Admin can put order discount and a button to apply discount. after applying the discount will show on Order total area.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to provide
Apply Coupon Code
or
Gift Cards

right after adding at least one product to order by default.
[image]